Has anyone compiled a list of all the philosophical works Nietzsche critiques in Beyond Good and Evil?
I know this isn't really a philosophy question; I just want to read everything Nietzsche read. I have a picture of him over my bed and I kiss his little forehead every night.
Also, why does he say synthetic a priori judgements are necessary to beings like us? (19) Also, does this imply that in some sense our biological capacities make the world we live in, and, if so, why does he then say that it's absurd to think that our organs make the world because they are also part of the world and they can't make themselves (22). Maybe I am messing up the distinction between the world and our experience of the world.
(Walter Kaufmann edition)

Have you checked some edition with index of names/subjects?

E.g. here

this is a good idea thank you
